# Im Having the following error ReferenceError: document is not defined with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dom

This happen when Im trying to use `ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')`

This is the code index.tsx:

```
import store from '../data/store'

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import App from './_app';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement)
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

And this is the code in App.tsx:

```
export interface IApplicationProps {}

const App: React.FunctionComponent<IApplicationProps> = (props) => {
  return (
      <div className="flex bg-[#E5E5E5]">
      <Sidebar />
      <Navbar title="Logo"/>
      <div className="px-6 h-[calc(100vh-72px)] overflow-y-scroll hide-scrollbar flex xl:flex-row flex-col-reverse">
        <div className='flex-1 h-fit pb-40'>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="/inventory" element={<Inventory />} />
            <Route path="/management" element={<Management />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: tsconfig.json is added